# FFMpeg Copy Live Stream (Limit to 60s file)

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I currently have a working way to get a live stream and start downloading it locally while it is still live.

`ffmpeg -i source_hls.m3u8 -c copy output.mkv -y`

The problem is I do not actually want to save the entire thing, I just periodically run another command on the output.mkv command to create a clip of part of the live stream.

I was wondering if it was possible to limit the output.mkv file to be only 60s long so once the stream goes over 1 minute it will just cut off the old video and be replaced by the new rolling video.

Is this possible or no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can come close, using the segment muxer.

```
ffmpeg -i source_hls.m3u8 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 out%02d.mkv -y
```

This will write to out00.mkv, then out01.mkv, then overwrite out00.mkv, next overwrite out01.mkv and so on.

The segment time is set at 60 seconds, so each segment will be around 60 seconds. The targets for splitting are 60,120,180,240... seconds of the input. However, video streams will be only be split at keyframes at or after the split target. So, if the first keyframe after t=59 is at 66, then the first segment will be 66s long. The next target is 120s. Let's say there's a KF at 121s, so the 2nd segment will be 66 to 121s = 55s long. Something to keep in mind when checking the segments.

Check the file modification times to see which segment contains the earlier data.

If you want to reduce the surplus duration, decrease segment_time and increase segment_wrap correspondingly. `segment_time x segment_wrap` should be `target saved duration + segment_time` long.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: ok one other question, lets say I run the command when the most recent is still being written and it only has 10s in the file, if I wanted to get the most recent 30s how would I go about getting the 10s from the file being written and then the last 20s of the file that is finished being written.

Comment: Hmmm btw just left this running to see if I could figure this out and when I let it run for over 1 minute I get this error:

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error writing trailer of path/to/out%02d.mkv: Invalid argument
frame= 3130 fps= 49 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:00.18 bitrate=N/A speed=0.938x
video:52256kB audio:875kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!

Comment: Add -report and run. Share link to report.

Comment: I logged out the output that the ffmpeg process was sending and it says "Error parsing AAC extradata, unable to determine samplerate." will this be because of the library im using to run this in node? (https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) because it works fine without doing it in node

Comment: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/files/3860496/ffmpeg-20191118-141819.log heres the log btw (I posted an issue on github with them also as it works without running on node)

Comment: Oh hey! I got it working through node now I switched to ffmpeg-cli, its working flawless. Now for the other question I had. So it is possible that the most recent file will still be currently getting written to, when I run the command to get 30s of the stream I want it to be the most recent 30s. How can I do this if its possible that the current file has 10s and not a full 30s. Is it possible to set 2 inputs and only get 30s from the 2 of them how I would want?

Comment: That will require saving to TS instead of MKV. Make copies of the two most recently written TS files. Then run `ffmpeg -sseof -30 -i "concat:file1.ts|file2.ts" -c copy out.mkv`

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you can use `-t duration`, i.e.:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 60 -i source_hls.m3u8 -c copy output.mkv
```

---

From [ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

```
-t duration (input/output)
```

> When used as an input option (before `-i`), limit the duration of data
> read from the input file.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output url), stop writing the
> output after its duration reaches duration.
>
> duration must be a time duration specification, see [(ffmpeg-utils)the
> Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1)
> manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax).
>
> -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.

---

`-t` argument examples:

- `11` - 11 seconds
- `11.111` - 11.111 seconds
- `1:11:11` - 11 hours, 11 minutes and 11 seconds

Comment: As far as I know adding the -t just will stop completely once it reaches the specified time. I do not think this will work and I am pretty sure I have tried this before.

Comment: It does work as expected, and by expected I mean it will record, in this case, 60 seconds and stop after that.